# Webpack puplicate ending in generated file

Tags: javascript, webpack

Example on [github](https://github.com/DimaIT/Webpack-duplicate-ending)

The problem is in duplicate file ending in generated by webpack files.
Webpack adds extra closing brackets and brakes file.

Example:

```
|- build/
|- app.js
|- one.js
|- test.js
```

app.js contains webpack config:

```
var webpack = require("webpack");
var compiler = webpack({
  entry: {
    generated: ['./test.js']
  },
  output: {
    path: "build",
    filename: "[name].js"
  }
}, function(err) {
  if(err) console.error(err);
});

compiler.watch('', function (err) {
  if(err) console.error(err);
});
```

test.js - webpack source

```
require('./one.js');
```

one.js - code source

```
console.log('hello from one');
```

After exacution I expect to get valid **generated.js** with ending like:

```
/***/ }
/******/ ]);
```

but I get:

```
/***/ }
/******/ ]);le');

/***/ }

/******/ });
```

I can suggest that  `le'` it's a part of `cannot resolve module` or `cannot find module`.
That take place with different configs and different files and brakes everething. I need your help.

**Update:**

For unknown reason extra ending not appears if webpack creates folder by itself.

Comment: My `generated.js`: http://pastebin.com/nkdyYTu0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to clean `build` directory before start building `generated.js`.

```
/******/ ]);le');
```

It is output from previous build.

Comment: In my case this appears even with empty `build`. But removing of directory helps, thanks.